Flutter GetX: How to obtain routes in stack, aka routing history?
I try to get access to the stack variable where GetX stores visited routes.
It is purely educational for now, but I think it can be useful sometimes.
I tried Get.routeTree.routes but it is just a list of named routes. If there are no named routes it is empty.
I tried Get.keys.keys but it is always empty no matter how many routes were visited.
Currently, I am searching in getx/lib/get_navigation/src /extension_navigation.dart but without success.
Any ideas?

It looks like GetX uses Navigator internally, so the problem is not GetX-related.
And the solution is simple: there is a package for that (surprise).
So, this is how I did it.
flutter pub add navigation_history_observer
Add observer to GetMaterialApp:
 return GetMaterialApp(
       home: const FirstScreen(),
       initialRoute: Routes.FIRST_SCREEN,
       getPages: Routes.routes,
       navigatorObservers: [NavigationHistoryObserver()],

NavigationHistory widget to add to every screen:
class NavigationHistory extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationHistory({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Wrap(alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              const Text("Routes in stack: ", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              for (Route page in NavigationHistoryObserver().history) 
              Text("${page.settings.name!}, ", style: 
              TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                         color: getColor(page.settings.name!)),)
            ]);
  }             
}

It works. This is what I see. Very useful while learning navigation API.

